# Does the IETF publish versions RFCs that include errata?

Tags: rfc, ietf

When reading an RFC published by the IETF, it's hard to know what content has been corrected without explicitly checking the errata. For example, in [RFC 7049 Section 2.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049#section-2.4.2), the following correction exists in the errata:

```
diff --git a/rfc7049.txt b/rfc7049.txt
index 5d29907..c7c20e6 100644
--- a/rfc7049.txt
+++ b/rfc7049.txt
@@ -886,7 +886,7 @@ RFC 7049                          CBOR                      October 2013
    and eight bytes 0x00).  In hexadecimal:
 
    C2                        -- Tag 2
-      29                     -- Byte string of length 9
+      49                     -- Byte string of length 9
          010000000000000000  -- Bytes content
```

But to realize this particular section was corrected, I'd have to go through the errata beforehand and write down all the sections that have corrections. Then, if I come across a section that was corrected, I'd have to look back at the errata and find what that particular correction was.

So, to simplify this process, does the IETF publish versions RFCs that *include* errata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, a standards track IETF RFC is a reference, and therefore, should *not* change. This is why errata are published separately. However, the IETF does indeed provide RFCs with the errata *included* with the following caveat:

> This is a purely informative rendering of an RFC that includes verified errata. This rendering may not be used as a reference.

For this particular RFC, one may find the version with errata included at the following location:
`https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/beta/errata/RFC7049.html`, which was navigated to from `https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7049/` by clicking the `with errata` button in the `Document > Formats` section.

Comment: The URL of the RFC rendered with errata has changed. Now it is: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc7049.html